# showcaseview after upgrade to flutter 3.7.1 not disable target click

Tags: android, flutter, dart, showcaseview

You can press target widget,which navigate to next page before complete showcases.

This problem happened after upgrade to flutter 3.7

**This is full code **

//main page

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:showcaseview/showcaseview.dart';

 void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
  }
```

//MyApp Page

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({super.key});

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
 //showCaseWidget
  home: ShowCaseWidget(
      disableMovingAnimation: true,
      disableScaleAnimation: true,
      builder: Builder(
          builder: (_) =>
              const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')),
      onFinish: () async {}),
      );
     }
  }
```

//MyHomePage

```
  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

 @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    final int _counter = 0;
//showCase keys
  final _increment = GlobalKey();
   final _decrement = GlobalKey();
  final _texxt = GlobalKey();

void navigateToPage(fun) {
   Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => ShowCaseWidget(
            builder: Builder(builder: (_) => fun), onFinish: () async 
{})));
}

 void _incrementCounter() {
navigateToPage(const Increment());
}

 void _textWidget() {
 navigateToPage(const TextWidget());
}

 void _decrementCounter() async {
  navigateToPage( const Decrement());
}

 @override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
  super.initState(); 
 //start showcase
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
  (_) => ShowCaseWidget.of(context)
      .startShowCase([_increment, _decrement, _texxt]),
   );
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: InkWell(
    onTap: _textWidget,
    child: Center(
      child: CustomShowcaseWidget(
        description: 'this is text widget ',
        globalKey: _texxt,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      CustomShowcaseWidget(
        description: 'this is increment floating button widget ',
        globalKey: _increment,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: "increment",
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
      CustomShowcaseWidget(
        description: 'this is decrement floating button widget ',
        globalKey: _decrement,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: "decrement",
          onPressed: _decrementCounter,
          tooltip: 'decrement',
          child: const Icon(Icons.minimize),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ), 
   );
  }
     }
```

//CustomShowcaseWidget

```
class CustomShowcaseWidget extends StatelessWidget {
final Widget child;
 final String description;
final GlobalKey globalKey;

 const CustomShowcaseWidget(
  {required this.description,
  required this.child,
  required this.globalKey,
  Key? key})
  : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => Showcase(
    key: globalKey,
    tooltipBackgroundColor: Colors.green,
    tooltipPadding:
        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
    showArrow: true,
    disableMovingAnimation: true,
    disableScaleAnimation: true,
    disableDefaultTargetGestures: true,
    description: description,
    descTextStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 
 20),
    child: child,
  );
}
```

// Increment Widget

```
 class Increment extends StatelessWidget {
  const Increment({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: const Center(
    child: Text("Increment Screen"),
    ),
  );
  }
}
```

//Decrement  Widget

```
 class Decrement extends StatelessWidget {
  const Decrement({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: const Center(
    child: Text("Decrement Screen"),
  ),
);
 }
}
```

//TextWidget

```
class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 const TextWidget({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: const Center(
      child: Text("Text Screen"),
     ),
    );
  }
 }
```

As shown in the pictures The Floating action button (+) is the target widget

[image]

This happened after click the target

[image]

Comment: can you include full sample snippet

Comment: I edited the question and added full sample snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved in the new version `showcaseview: ^2.0.2` of the library